# Passing settings from view to element with default values

Tags: php, cakephp

I'm trying to pass settings like this:

```
$mySettings = array(
    'settingOne' => 'someValue',
    'settingTwo' => 5,
    'settingThree' => true
);
```

from the view into an element like so:

```
echo $this->element('foobar', $mySettings);
```

How would I set the default values for them inside of the element?

Or is it better to set them somewhere else? If so, where and how?

Thank you.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Write default code in `appsController` like below

```
$mySettings = array(
    'settingOne' => 'someValue',
    'settingTwo' => 5,
    'settingThree' => true
);
$this->set('foobar', $mySettings);
```

And If you want to Modify `$mySettings` then you have to write same code in Controller that you want to change from.

You have to use `foobar` variable in element like

```
$foobar['settingOne'];
$foobar['settingTwo'];
$foobar['settingThree'];
```

Comment: Thank you but how would I set a default value for each setting?

Comment: You want to say that set default value of mySetting If values are set then use new value other wise it takes default value. Am i right?

Comment: You have to write `$mySettings` code in App controller and If you want to modify default value for particular view then write `$mySetting` code in view file. Do you understand what I mean?

Comment: Can you please give me an example? Thank you.

Comment: Check my updated answer and If you do not understand then let me know

Answer (score 1):

if the setting entries are dynamic, you can try this:

```
function element($entry, $settings, $default = null) {
    if (isset($settings[$entry])) {
        return $settings[$entry];
    } else {
        return $default;
    }
}
```

if the setting entries are static, you'd better define a class, each entry as a property.

Answer (score 0):

The keys you pass in are transformed into variables

So just do

```
if (!isset($theConfigKey)) {
    $theConfigKey = ...
}
```